# Hitachi SimpleDrive mini not recognised

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

My [Hitachi SimpleDrive mini](http://www.hgst.com/support/index-files/sd-mini-technical-support) USB HDD, 500 GB, is not being recognized on my Windows 7 machine. It's LEDs flash with a delay, continuously. After I plug it out, Windows asks me to format it.

I have a lot of data I don't want to lose. Can any body help me recover my USB HDD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use easeus partition recovery or partition wizrad home. Try to repair partition or recover lost partition. If you are lucky you can get your whole data back. If it is caused due to partition error then this method  will be much faster than using recovery tools.

http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/

http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

Data recovery tools take lot of time and they need another hard disk to store recovered data. First try to restore entire partition. If it fails go for data recovery tool.